# How powerful do cold gas thrusters normally get?

Tags: falcon-9, engines, attitude, thrust, flight-control

Modern rockets like the Falcon 9 use cold gas thrusters for steering on landing approach when the engines are dead.

Cold gas thrusters are common in smaller satellites and spacecraft, which way a fraction of a rocket's first stage.

So I'm wondering: how much force can you get from a cold gas thruster? How powerful do these normally get? I'd be especially interested in specific references to powerful cold gas thrusters or to the rockets that use them.

Comment: I added "normally" because there is no limit to how much force is possible without constraining the problem to reality somehow. Please feel free to edit further.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for catching my typos!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like usually 100 newtons - 440+ newtons of thrust. This depends on many different factors, though, including the gas being used, the pressure its being fired at, and the size of the nozzle/the mass of whats being fired.

This wikipedia page has information about the gemini spacecrafts' thrusters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_control_system

Correction: Falcon 9 second stage uses the draco thruster, which produces 400 newtons. However I'm unable to find any information about the booster.

> Each Draco thruster generates 400 newtons (90 lbf) of thrust.
> They are used as Reaction Control System (RCS) thrusters on both the Dragon spacecraft, and on the Falcon 9 launch vehicle second-stage.

Comment: Thanks, @Not_Shark! Did you see the 1000 N somewhere? Do you know of any reference to a cold gas thruster rated that high? This would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I cant find any info about high thrust rcs, although i clarified my  message about the falcon 9, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: "Falcon 9 second stage uses the draco thruster" – F9 does not use the Draco. It uses nitrogen cold-gas thrusters. "However I'm unable to find any information about the booster" – Same. Both stages of the F9 use nitrogen cold-gas thrusters. Draco is only used on the Crew Dragon and Cargo Dragon and was used on Dragon v1. The first Starship prototypes had nitrogen cold-gas thrusters as well. Those were always said to be temporary and to be replaced with custom-developed methalox hot-gas thrusters, however, those have since been deleted and SpaceX is now going for using ullage gas for RCS.